# RAID0 SSD performance degredation

Tags: performance, ssd, raid, trim

I have a computer built to acquire uncompressed 2048 x 2048 16 bit images at 100 frames per second in real time, writing to disk.  A RAID0 of SSDs is thus the only option.

For the past month or so, this setup has worked great.  Recently, however, the frame rate has been sporadic during data acquisition, indicating that the disk write performance has dropped. I believe this is most likely due to the fact that I have completely filled and emptied the disk array multiple times and the performance of the SSDs has degraded since my RAID controller doesn't pass TRIM commands to the drives.

Is there any way to restore the performance of the array?

Relevant information:
RAID controller: LSI Megaraid 9271
SSDs: 4 x 512GB Crucial m4

Comment: Does it need to be that PCIe RAID Controller? Maybe you can use a 7-series mainboard with an integrated Intel RAID controller. The Intel RST driver does [support TRIM for RAID since version 11.2](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6161/intel-brings-trim-to-raid0-ssd-arrays-on-7series-motherboards-we-test-it).

Comment: Do you think the Intel RST will be fast enough to support my write throughput requirements? (over 1GB/s)

Comment: This [blog post](http://www.4d.com/blog/4d-ssd-watch-august-31.html) seems to answer your questions. he is testing with a 7-series mainboard, 4 SSDs and an benchmark shows more than 1 GB transfer rate. Compare the results with your LSI RAID controller with [ATTO](http://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/1749/atto-disk-benchmark-v2-46/). Let me know, if this helped you and if its worth an answer.

Comment: Thanks, but the LSI controller seems to be much faster. In the blog post, the writes maxed out at slightly less than 1 GB/s whereas with the LSI, ATTO reports writes of over 3 GB/s. I'd like to find a solution that keeps the current hardware.

Comment: Ok, back to start: Are [firmware and driver](http://www.lsi.com/products/storagecomponents/Pages/MegaRAIDSAS9271-8i.aspx#four) up to date? I see a program called "MegaRAID Storage Manager" on their site. Maybe this program offers a scheduled TRIM support like the old Intel SSD Toolbox does for Windows XP systems back in the days

Comment: Both are up to date. I have the MegaRAID Storage Manager, and it doesn't allow such an option. I believe that no discrete RAID controllers to date offer TRIM support, so I'm really looking for a solution that could restore performance every once in awhile.  For instance, I wouldn't be averse to completely wiping the array every so often (the OS is on another drive), but this didn't help (a diskpart "clean all"). Is there something similar that would restore  the SSDs to their "original" state?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried upgrading firmware of your SSD? http://www.crucial.com/support/firmware.aspx
I would back up first tho, can't say how safe is upgrading with Raid option.